# Creating Subtitles with video hosted on Vimeo server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I need help with the Creating/Adding subtitles in sync with the video hosted on vimeo server. This video is embedded in a HTML page. I have the subtitles saved in .srt /.vtt / Notepad files. 
Kindly suggest me the best possible options which can also used for commercial purpose. Please see the below image screensot[image: Please see the Image screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Customized player with vimeo is pseudo-impossible, but you can use subtitles with the follow link.

Your welcome:

https://github.com/Yomguithereal/vimeo-srt

Comment: Hello @Elio, 
I tried using this, but unfortunately this is not working for me.

Comment: Hi there!, sorry for the delay (2 years! =/ haha i really don`t use this site).

I worked on this and works for me:
https://github.com/eliooses/vimeo-srt-uiux

But i haved no idea of the functions of git :v, whatever, Vimeo now supports subtitles.

Best regards, and again: my apologies for the delay.